# Referencing external URLs

Tags: django

I'm trying to find a way to write a proper view in Django that references an external URL.

For examples, typically I could write a simple view as follows:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def my_view(request):
    if True:
        return HttpResponse('<h1 >hello world</h1 >')
```

Alternately, we can we can reference a template with `render_to_response`. How do we reference an external URL such as "google" for example?

Comment: What do you mean by "reference" the URL? What do you want to happen?

Comment: what I would like to do is load a URL from a template. In this case, I would like to load a json file. The URL from the template is being processed by the urlconf. Is there any way to bypass that?

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. What you do in the response is tell the users browser what to do - normally display some HTML, but alternatively redirect to some other URL. What **exactly** do you want to tell the browser to do?

Comment: I would like the browser to redirect to some other URL. What I'm trying to do do is load JSON data into a JQUERY function which is built in to the template. I need to be able to call an external page to do this however. I would then also like to call a page that is within my file system later.

Comment: You are trying to mix up logic here. Just send the response, and do the redirection from the response to the jquery function

Comment: I think the only thing the guy wants to do, is load some data from a static JSON file, and wants to know how he can do this, if the file is on his server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) to redirect the user to the provided url.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def my_view(request):
    if True:
       return HttpResponseRedirect('http://stackoverflow.com')
```

Comment: What would happen if I wanted to reference a json file within my server's file system?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Well let me be more clear. I have a template that loads a JQUERY function. The function depends on a url to load json data. When the URL is called, it goes through the URLCONF. The problem is that I don't know what the proper "response" is in the view? I need to have the view access the URL so that the template can load the JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your comments on the first answer, here is what I think is your problem:

You want to load a static `JSON` file, and you wish to know how to do this.

Okay, so if this said file is on your server, then you are going to have to use the `static` url tag. If you want to load this `JSON` file from a place that is not on your server, just put in the full web address, like so: `http://www.google.com`

Now, if this said JSON file is on your server, then it is a separate issue. In this case you are dealing with a static file. And [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/) is a nice place where you can learn about static files.

If however, this JSON file changes, then you have a different problem entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You're still not thinking on trends of what the browser can do. The browser can't access things on your server's filesystem, of course. It can only load content that is served up by something, whether it's Django, your static media server, or an external server.

But I don't understand why you want Django to redirect to this content. Either you load the JSON directly from the Javascript, or you load it from the filesystem within your view and pass it to your template so it's included in the page content already.